# retrieving usernames in a system in bash

Tags: linux, bash, passwd

I'm new to scripting in bash and would like to retrieve all user names of a Linux system along with their home directories. Each username got to be in a single line.
Is this is the best way to do this? or is there any better way?

```
#! /bin/bash
# list all users accounts using the /etc/passwd file
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1," ",$6}'
```

I ask you kindly to advise

Comment: You don't need a pipe. `awk` can read directly from the file: `awk -F: '...' /etc/passwd`.

Comment: You could filter out the "nologin" entries if you only want real users.

Comment: active users (ie. valid shell): `awk -F: 'FNR==NR { sh[$1]++; next } $7 in sh { print $1,$6 }' /etc/shells <(getent passwd)`

Comment: thanx so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner commented, awk -F: '{print $1," ",$6}' /etc/passwd is better.

You can try the following :

```
 wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbareck7/python_journey/main/nakerah/milestone00.py
 cp /etc/passwd milestone_00.txt
 python3 milestone00.py
```

It's a a python script which takes as input /etc/password file, and return a JSON list as bellow.

```
[                                                                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "user_name": "root",                                                                                                                                                                  
    "user_id": "0",                                                                                                                                                                       
    "home_dir": "/root",                                                                                                                                                                  
    "login_shell": "/bin/bash",                                                                                                                                                           
    "normal_user": false                                                                                                                                                                  
},                                                                                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "user_name": "daemon",                                                                                                                                                                
    "user_id": "1",                                                                                                                                                                       
    "home_dir": "/usr/sbin",                                                                                                                                                              
    "login_shell": "/usr/sbin/nologin",                                                                                                                                                   
    "normal_user": false                                                                                                                                                                  
},......
 .........
]
```

Comment: Many thanks for everyone who answered my question